# Plotly graph to combine two maps with drop down menu

Tags: python, plotly

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import healthindex
import wealthindex

# Define the dropdown menu options
dropdown_options = ["Health Index", "Wealth Index"]

# Define the callback function for the dropdown
def update_graph(change):
    selected_value = change.new
    clear_output()
    if selected_value == "Health Index":
        display(healthindex.fig)
    elif selected_value == "Wealth Index":
        display(wealthindex.fig)

# Create the dropdown widget
dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=dropdown_options, description="Select Index:")

# Register the callback function with the dropdown
dropdown.observe(update_graph, names='value')

# Display the dropdown
display(dropdown)

# Display the initial graph
display(healthindex.fig)
```

My issue is that this is only showing the initial graph when I change the value to `"Wealth Index"`; please help me fix this:

[image]